# perl bless with fat comma

Tags: perl, syntax

I know that perl bless can take in 1 or 2 arg as stated in [perlbless](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#bless,-blessed,-and-ref). However, I do not understand what bless with a fat comma in the below code is doing? Is it the same as `bless \$value,$class;` ?

```
# Construct the tie.
sub TIESCALAR { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $value = shift || 0;

    bless \$value => $class;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fat comma is just another way of writing the `comma`.  You can see this with :

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'bless \$value => $class'
bless \$value, $class;
-e syntax OK
```

An interesting discussion can be found [here](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2013/04/the-fat-comma-and-clarity.html) too.

Comment: This is not quite true, although it’s true enough in this situation. Unlike the normal one, **the fat comma *autoquotes* its LHS bareword operand** if necessary. Notice how different the output is in these two calls: `sub show_pair { my($this, $that) = @_; print "$this is $that.\n" }
show_pair(time, time);
show_pair(time => time);` produces `1402245177 is 1402245177.
time is 1402245177.`  There are more exotic cases still.